# How do I find if a particular ID has a record of a specific value?

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a table `booking` where a `peopleid` can have multiple bookings. What's the best way to find people with at least 1 booking of `active`? Other booking values are `cancelled`,`closed`

I was thinking this, but I feel like there's gotta be a more efficient method:

```
select a.peopleid
     , sum(case status.status_desc when 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as counted
  from booking a
 inner join people
    on a.peopleid = people.peopleid
 inner join status
   on a.statusid = status.statusid
group by a.personid
```

I plan on doing a `left join` to this to get a simple `yes` or `no` indicator for if a person has at least one active booking or not

grain of booking is `bookingid|statusid|peopleid` and 1 person can have multiple bookings

Comment: think is easier if you show the whole table structure.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the people with at least one active booking, just do a simple `JOIN` and put the desired status in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.peopleid
FROM booking AS b
JOIN status AS s ON b.statusid = s.statusid
WHERE s.status_desc = 'active'
```

There's no need to join with `people` (unless you want to get other information about the person, which isn't shown in the question). And there's no need to count the matches; if there are no rows that match the `status_desc = 'active'` condition they won't be returned by the `JOIN`. `SELECT DISTINCT` gets rid of the duplicates when someone has multiple bookings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXiSTS to check which user has at least one booking that match the condition.

```
select p.peopleid
from   people p
where  exists (select 1
               from   booking b
               join   status  s
               where  b.peopleid = p.peopleid
                      s.statusid = b.statusid
               and    s.status_desc = 'active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use count with a WHERE clause.

```
select a.peopleid
     , COUNT(*) as counted
 from booking a
 inner join people
   on a.peopleid = people.peopleid
inner join status
 on a.statusid = status.statusid
where status.status_desc = 'active'
group by a.personid
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple join:

```
select p.* from people p
join booking b on b.peopleid  = a.peopleid 
join status on status.statusid = b.statusid
where status.status_desc = 'active'
```

If you don't need any other info from the the people like their name, address.. then you can skip the people table and get the ID from the booking table.